# I am creating a text editor app in C#...few bugs i cant overcome

Tags: c#

1. In my app, when I create a new window (form2) (from file>new) and close the previous window (Form1), the newly created window (form2) closes as well. How do i make sure that only the window I close is closed? For example, when form1 and form2 are open and I close form1, I want form2 to remain open.
2. I use a `RichTextBox` in the editor. How do I go to a particular line when I specify a line number in a text box?
3. I want to create a drop-down color chooser from the tool strip (like in Word or Excel). How can I do this?

its not a dialog box and a code snippet that moves the cursor to particular line when given in Text box is appreciate...

Comment: need more info on 1. how are you creating and showing the forms?

Comment: Form1 f =new Form1(); f.Show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Can you post a code snippet showing how you're creating the second window? Are you setting the owner property?

2) My bet would the [CaretPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx) property.

3) Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/ColorButton.aspx). The author just create a form with the floatting drop drown and then proceeds to show it, hide it, ... when appropriate. Clever and down to earth.

Answer (score 0):

1. more info needed
2. count up the length of each line before the line you want to goto, then just set the `SelectionStart` property to that value;
3. Have you looked at the default `ColorDialog` control?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I have used to fill two list boxes with all system colours and theme colours. Perhaps you could adapt for use in a combo box?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

  /// <summary>
        /// loads the colours
        /// </summary>
        private void LoadColours()
        {
            try
            {
                Color testColor = ProfessionalColors.ButtonCheckedGradientBegin;
                Type colorType = testColor.GetType();

                PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public );

                lvColours.Items.Clear();

                foreach ( PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo in propInfoList )
                {
                    Color color = ( Color ) oPropertyInfo.GetValue( null, null );

                    ListViewItem oListViewItem = new ListViewItem( GetColorName( oPropertyInfo.Name ) );

                    oListViewItem.BackColor = color;

                    lvColours.Items.Add( oListViewItem );
                }

                Type ProfType = typeof( ProfessionalColors );

                PropertyInfo[] PropInfos = ProfType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public );

                foreach ( PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo in PropInfos )
                {
                    Color oColor =(Color) oPropertyInfo.GetValue( null, null );

                    ListViewItem oListViewItem = new ListViewItem( GetColorName( oPropertyInfo.Name ) );

                    oListViewItem.BackColor = oColor;

                    lvProfessionalColours.Items.Add( oListViewItem );
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
            }
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Color Name
    /// </summary>
    protected string GetColorName( string strFullName )
    {
        string strName = "";
        int idx = strFullName.LastIndexOf( "." );
        if ( idx != -1 )
        {
            strName = strFullName.Substring( idx );
        }
        else
        {
            return strFullName;
        }
        return strName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first form is passed to `Application.Run()` then it will terminate the whole program when you close it. Instead of closing the form, you can simply hide it.